# Isabelle/HOL: access interpretation in another locale

Tags: isabelle

There's an Isabelle/HOL library that I want to build on with new definitions and proofs.  The library defines locale2, which I'd like to build upon.  Inside locale2, there's an interpretation of locale1.

To extend locale2 in a separate theory, I define locale3 = locale2.  Inside locale3, however, I can't figure out how to access locale2's interpretation of locale1.  How can I do that?  (Am I even going about this in the right way at all?)

Below is an MWE.  This is the library theory with the locale I want to extend:

```
theory ExistingLibrary
  imports Main
begin

(* this is the locale with the function I want *)
locale locale1 = assumes True
begin

fun inc :: "nat ⇒ nat"
  where "inc n = n + 1"

end

(* this is the locale that interprets the locale I want *)
locale locale2 = assumes True
begin

interpretation I: locale1
  by unfold_locales auto

end
end
```

This is my extension theory.  My attempt is at the bottom, causing an error:

```
theory MyExtension
  imports ExistingLibrary
begin

locale locale3 = locale2
begin

definition x :: nat
  where "x = I.inc 7" (* Undefined constant: "I.inc" *)

end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Interpretations inside a context last only until the end of the context. When the context is entered again, you have to repeat the interpretation to make the definitions and theorems available:

```
locale 3 = locale2 begin
interpretation I: locale1 <proof>
```

For this reason, I recommend to split the first interpretation step into two:

1. A lemma with a name that proves the goal of the interpretation step.
2. The `interpretation` command itself which can be proved `by(rule`lemma`)`

If you want the interpretation to take place whenever you open the locale and whenever you interpret the locale, then `sublocale` instead of `interpretation` might be better.